# Interaction between KOMA, eulerpx, \chapter, and \mathbf: Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition

Tags: fonts, errors, koma-script, math-fonts, euler

I'm using `pdflatex` from the TeX Live distribution on Arch Linux. `xelatex` and `lualatex` have the same issue.

Minimum failing example:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage{eulerpx}

\begin{document}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\chapter{foo}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\end{document}
```

yields:

```
! Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.
\reserved@b ->\relax
                     \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathbf  \fi \use@mathgroup...
l.7 \(\mathbf{foo}
                  \)
```

Either removing `\usepackage{eulerpx}` or switching to `\documentclass{report}` fixes the problem. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? It's driving me mad, since I want to use KOMA, and I want to be able to easily mix Palatino and Euler in math mode. Alternatively does anyone know of a drop in replacement for `eulerpx`?

This seems to be linked to the use of `\chapter`, `\section`, etc.; the following also all fail with the same error:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage{eulerpx}

\begin{document}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\section{foo}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage{eulerpx}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\chapter{foo}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage{eulerpx}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\section{foo}
\(\mathbf{foo}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I experienced the same problem in the same situation (surprise!). A way around it (in Jun 2022) was to download the eulerpx.sty package directly from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eulerpx. I downloaded version 0.3.1. The version in my system was from whatever came with TeX Live 2020/Debian. This file doesn't have the \let\mathbf=\relax mentioned by egreg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the `eulerpx` package says

```
%% Get rid of the existing \mathbf font
\let\mathbf=\relax
```

which is not really a good thing to do.

What is the problem? The `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}` command that follows, will not change the internal definition of `\mathbf`. This is witnessed by doing

```
\expandafter\show\csname mathf \endcsname
```

after the first `\(\mathbf{foo}\)` (because math alphabets are really only allocated at first usage). This will show

```
> \mathbf =macro:
->\relax \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathbf  \fi \use@mathgroup \M@OT1 {8}.
```

on the terminal, which is the same as you get without loading `eulerpx`, only the final number will change. On the other hand, removing the bad `\let\mathbf=\relax` line, we get

```
> \mathbf =macro:
->\relax \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathbf  \fi \use@mathgroup \M@U {8}.
```

Can you see the small difference? Well, that's the one. Indeed, the issue disappears.

There is no need whatsoever to “get rid of the existing `\mathbf` font”. Math alphabets are allocated “on demand”, so there is *no* existing `\mathbf` font. There is a `\mathbf` command, but it will do a shake to the font selection scheme at its first usage in order to pick up the requested font.

(There are a few other glitches in `eulerpx`, actually.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It seems strange that this only happens with KOMA and when there's some kind of section header present; do you have any idea what it is about this particular combination that causes the issue?

Answer (score 2):

#### In the Modern Toolchain

Since you mentioned you’re able to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could download [the OpenType version of Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) and use `unicode-math`.  In Linux, save `euler.otf` to `~/.fonts/` to install it only for yourself, or to `/usr/local/share/fonts/` to install it system-wide.  (Subdirectories also work.)

A good companion sans-serif font by the same designer as AMS Euler and Palatino would be Optima, whose clone URW Classico is available via TUG’s [`getnonfreefonts`](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) script.  (You want to install it to your `TEXMFLOCAL` directory, with `--sys`.)

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{URW Classico}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont{euler.otf}[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                               bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                               cal,bfcal,frak,bffrak}]

\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\symbf{#1}}
                               
\begin{document}
\[ a \vectorsym{i} \times b \vectorsym{j} = ab \vectorsym{k}
   \quad\mathbf{iff}\quad \vectorsym{i} \cdot \vectorsym{j} = 0 \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Neo Euler/Asana Math/TeX Gyre Pagella sample]

This preamble should give you similar output to `eulerpx`, except that `\mathbf` gives you the bold text font.  (The least-contrived example I could think of was wanting to emphasize the word **iff**.  Notice the ﬀ ligature and the difference between the **i** in **iff** and the basis vector.)  To get bold math letters for vectors, use `\symbf`.

You could instead add the `bf=sym` option to `unicode-math`, which makes `\mathbf` an alias for `\symbf`.  You then, if you ever need a bit of bold text in math mode, would write something like `\textnormal{\bfseries iff}`.

You can change the `\mathbf` font with the `BoldFont=` option of `\setmathrm`, e.g.

```
\setmathrm{URWClassico}[
   UprightFont = *-Regular,
   BoldFont = *-Bold,
   ItalicFont = *-Italic,
   BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
   Extension = .otf]
```

There is also a `\setboldmathrm` command, but that changes the output of `\mathrm` in `\mathversion{bold}`, which unfortunately this set-up does not support.

If you would prefer ISO style, with Euler only for constants such as e, i and π, you can change `[math-style=upright]` to `[math-style=ISO]`.

If you don’t like the spacing of Euler’s subscripts and superscripts, you can pass `\setmathfont` the options `script-features={}` and `sscript-features={}`.  This will also disable the wider, more-legible letters.

#### A Workaround for PDFLaTeX

If you need to use legacy 8-bit fonts, `eulerpx` is compatible with `bm` for bold vector symbols, and you can use `\textnormal{\bfseries ...}` for bold text in math mode.

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage{amsmath,eulerpx,bm,tgpagella,classico,inconsolata}

\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
                               
\begin{document}
\[ a \vectorsym{i} \times b \vectorsym{j} = ab \vectorsym{k}
   \quad\textnormal{\bfseries iff}\quad \vectorsym{i} \cdot \vectorsym{j} = 0 \]
\end{document}
```

[image: AMS Euler/newpx/Pagella sample]

Comment: Funnily enough, this is actually exactly what I ended up doing to work around the problem (and I was also already using Optima as my sans-serif)!